# How do I isolate floated content?

Tags: css

I am pulling blog posts in from the blogger JSON api into my page. The posts are HTML formatted. Some of the posts have floated content; an image, for instance, that is floated left with text to the right that is shorter than the image. The title and date of the post below it are pushed to the right as well. I remember there being an esoteric way within CSS to isolate float within a div. I can't remember how. And I don't remember what it is even called. I've been searching all day. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sandy Reads - News</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <section id="posts">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Sandy Reads <small>News</small></h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var key = "Redacted";
            var blogId = "Redacted";
            var resource = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/" + blogId + "/posts?maxResults=10&key=" + key;

            $.getJSON(resource, function (data) {
                var items = [];
                $.each(data.items, function (key, val) {
                    var kind = val.kind;
                    if (kind !== 'blogger#post')
                        return;

                    var blogId = val.id;
                    var title = val.title;
                    var content = val.content;
                    var date = moment(val.updated);

                    items.push("<li id='" + blogId + "' class='post'>" +
                        "<a href='blog.html?id=" + blogId + "'><h3>" + title + "</h3></a>" +
                        "<i>" + date.format('MMMM Do YYYY') + "</i></div>" +
                        "<div>" + content + "</div>" + 
                        "</li>");
                });

                $("<ul/>", {
                    "class": "list-group my-new-list",
                    html: items.join("")
                }).appendTo("#posts");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably thinking of `overflow: hidden`, but which element you apply it to depends on what your markup looks like. I can tell you to apply it to the parent of the float, but if the content that is being pushed aside appears in this same parent, then that's not going to help.

OK, so your script generates posts in a series of `li.post` elements. The content appears in a `div` following the title and date. You can either set `li.post` to clear floats, or apply `overflow: hidden` to the `div`. (There is a spurious `</div>` end tag after your post date that you may want to account for.)